# How many shards should I use with Elasticsearch on a dev & CI environment?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

By default Elasticsearch is configured to start with 5 shards.

Is there a reason to use 5 shards locally (on my development machine) and on the continuous integration server (for integration tests)? Is it better to use 1?

Obviously I don't care about scalability in those cases, I just want the simplest setup.

Comment: Than why you want to change it from 5 to 1?

Comment: Because I've got random errors about shard stuff and I'd like to avoid running 5 lucene instances for nothing.

Comment: Interessting, so perhpas you have a problem with the shards and we should check the errors. I never had probs with elastic on a centOS machine with the standrad config of 5 shards. But test 1 out and post some infos if there is still a problem. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest setup is 1 primary shard, 0 replicas.

If you only have one node and replica count is >0 it will always be `yellow`. Not a problem per se, but those will not be needed.

If you want to test search response time with that one shard, for example, it depends on some factors if `1` is enough or you need more. The simplest rule of thumb is to have shards no larger than 30-50GB, for example. But this number also depends on factors.

So, I'd say if you have one node, start with 1 primary, 0 replicas. If that primary is too "large", think about having more primaries (each shard will do part of the work and each will use one core CPU for searching).

Comment: "30-50GB" Well that answers my question, we are talking about a dev machine so probably not more than a dozen MB ;) 1 shard 0 replicas is good then!

Answer (score 0):

Once you've pushed some data with a specific shard configuration, you cannot set a different number of shards without re-index your data. So my guess is that the default configuration of elasticsearch is made so that you can scale your cluster to 5 nodes (then each node gets one shard) without headaches.

from the [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/overallocation.html):

> A new index in Elasticsearch is allotted five primary shards by default. That means that we can spread that index out over a maximum of five nodes, with one shard on each node. That’s a lot of capacity, and it happens without you having to think about it at all!